Differential 1-forms over an (hyper)elliptic curve
Given am elliptic curve $E: y^2=x^3+ax+b$, a nice basis for $\Omega^1$ (for the holomorphic 1-forms) might be $\{\frac{dx}{y}\}$.
Given a hyperelliptic curve $H: y^2=P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is of degree $2g$ or $2g+1$, by this MSE post (user8268 answered) , a suitable basis for the holomorphic 1-forms is $\frac{x^kdx}{y}$, $k=0,\dots,g-1$.
In the same fashion of the elliptic curve case, we know we can identify $H$ with a $g$-dimensional complex torus whose generetors are the periods $\int_{\gamma_{1,k}} \frac{x^kdx}{y}$ and $\int_{\gamma_{2,k}} \frac{x^kdx}{y}$ where $\gamma_{1,k}$ and $\gamma_{2,k}$ (for all $k=0,\dots,g-1$) are basis elements of $H_1$ the first homology.
A few days ago I read the book (the theorem I read is in the beggining of 4.3.6): Bifurcations of Planar Vector Fields and Hilbert's Sixteenth Problem (I think the specific theorem I'm reffering to changed a bit in some newer versions).
Here is the theorem (yellow):


So we got a relation between the integrals of $\frac{x^kdx}{y}$ and the integrals of $x^kydx$.
But who are $x^kydx$? where did they come from? That is the first time I saw a use for these forms.
Thanks in advance.
